# paste in insertmode without indent i.e. `<C-r>*` without indent

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste

I want to do `:set paste`, *paste*, `:set nopaste` in one keyboard shortcut  in insertmode (`<C-r>*`)

In visualmode, with `vnoremap p "+p`  works with no indent. But in insertmode, this `<C-r>*` gives indent. How I can make `<C-r>*` work without indent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> combo in insert mode (see `:h i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O`).

If setting `:h 'paste'` is needed, here are the mappings to do this (kind of emulating [tpope/vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin):

```
    nnoremap <silent>[op :setl paste<Bar>au InsertLeave * ++once setl nopaste<CR>O
    nnoremap <silent>]op :setl paste<Bar>au InsertLeave * ++once setl nopaste<CR>o
    nnoremap <silent>yop :setl paste<Bar>au InsertLeave * ++once setl nopaste<CR>S
```

Comment: `inoremap <C-R> <C-R><C-O>` in `.vimrc` seems a good option as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a setting for that but with the `:set paste` and `:set nopaste` commands you can do this mapping:

```
:inoremap <silent> <C-R>* <Esc>:set paste<CR>i<C-R>*<Esc>:set nopaste<CR>
```